# Image not showing 2nd url page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Sorry if my title is a bit weird, I wasn't sure how to properly make a title for this. I'm using Laravel and the problem I'm having is that if I go to the 3rd url in my page my image isn't showing. It shows if I'm on the 1st url but not the 2nd and I can't understand why.

For example:

I can view the image at the url `http://localhost/site` and at `http://localhost/site/a` but not `http://localhost/site/a/b`

My public.blade.php

```
    <body>
    <!-- BEGIN MAIN WRAPPER CONTENT -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- BEGIN MOBILE LOGO SECTION -->
        <div class="visible-xs logo">
            <img src="{!! asset("img/logo1.png") !!}">
        </div>
        <!-- END MOBILE LOGO SECTION -->

        <!-- BEGIN MENU SECTION -->
        @include('menus::menu')
        <!-- END MENU SECTION -->

        <!-- BEGIN MAIN CONTENT SECTION -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT SECTION -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @yield('content')

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="footer visible-xs">
                            <p>
                                Designed by <br />
                                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="{!! asset("img/footer.png") !!}"> <!-- THIS IS THE IMAGE THAT IS GIVING ME PROBLEMS -->
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT SECTION -->
        </div>
        <!-- END MAIN CONTENT SECTION -->
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN WRAPPER CONTENT -->
```

I hope I explained clearly. If not please let me know.

Comment: Doesn't seem clear to me. Have you tried including the footer.png at the start? do you have permissions on the image? is that the correct path? can you access it through opening the url in a new page?

Comment: Develope this question pls

Comment: you mean you are able to display images in the url `www.xyz.com/a` and `www.xyz.com/a/b` and you are not able to display in `www.xyz.com/a/b/c` ?

Comment: @ab_in - yes that is correct, but I've changed my question a bit. I had made a mistake and it's actually the 2nd url and not the 3rd. I don't have a 3rd url

Comment: I've edited my question I hope it's better now.

Comment: okay , first check in both case  through inspect element in browser on image image path is correct ?

Comment: and also try  URL::to("img/footer.png") in src

Comment: @Nikki show the rendered image path of both situations.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
url("img/logo1.png")
```

instead of

```
asset("img/logo1.png")
```